# Dual state variable filter HP24 output

Tags: analog, transfer-function, active-filter, signal-theory, calculation

So I've been playing with 4-stage state variable filter (SVF hereinafter) to get a voltage-controlled filter with Highpass 24db/octave (HP24), LP24 and BP12 outputs. Unfortunately, reading about these filters and experimenting with them led me to the conclusion that this schematic is way too unstable to be practical - single-resonant-peak output has a singularity in the frequency response and even at low Q leads to oscillations. I won't get into much detail here, since that is not the question.

I've switched my attention then to 2 2-pole SVFs chained together:
[image: Two 2-pole SVFs chained together schematic]

Using this schematic, one can easily get HP12, BP6, LP12, BP12, LP24 and an asymmetric bandpass outputs by simply tapping into different parts of the circuit:

[image: 2-pole SVFs frequency response]

By subtracting the BP12 output from the input one can get a notch output as well. However, my interest lies in obtaining a HP24 filter from this schematic; No simple and/or obvious subtraction/addition combination seems to work.

I've read then about multimode filters which use complex pole mixing of a 4-stage lowpass filter to get different outputs ([MMF Link 1](http://www.soundsemiconductor.com/downloads/AN701.pdf), [MMF Link 2](https://electricdruid.net/multimode-filters-part-2-pole-mixing-filters/))

[image: Pole-mixing filter]

By selecting A,B,C,D,E coefficients one can get nearly any filter response they want, including LP, HP, BP, Notch and AP with any dB per octave rolloff. So, I've had a thought that maybe a similar HP24 filter is hiding somewhere in my dual 2-pole SVF topology (and I have to use integrators, unfortunately, and making four 1-pole SVFs and then pole-mix them seems like a bit of an overcomplicated solution)

So, my questions are:

1. Does pole-mixing work for my two 2-stage SVF topology?
2. Is my assumption correct that HP24 filter is hiding somewhere in this schematic, the only question remaining are the summing coefficients?
3. If so, what are the coefficients for it and what other filter responses could be achieved in this schematic?
4. How does one calculate these coefficients **from the start** both for the 4-pole MMF filter and for my schematic?

Comment: It ought to work but depends on layout and stray positive feedback that can be suppressed by nearby grounds. Let me simulate it.

Comment: Of course HP 24 or even HP 48 is much easier with Sallen & Key

Comment: The 2x2 SVF seems to work best for me with R12 feeding back into U2 instead of U6 then disconnect R14

Comment: OF course if you need a good lab instrument, Khron-Hite would be a great choice https://www.krohn-hite.com/34AData.pdf

Comment: The SVF equations are here https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu543/tidu543.pdf  and digital tuner kit here https://www.ti.com/tool/TIPD160?keyMatch=FILTER%20PRO%20DOWNLOAD

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Changing the resistor feedback as you say makes this filter a 4-stage SVF, which I am trying to avoid - it is very unstable near situation where only one resonant peak at high Q is observed and requires very good matching both of the integrators and high-precision passive components. Way too complex.

Comment: That might be trimmable on the unity gain feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

As far as the parasitic oscillations are concerned, you have cascaded full GBW Op Amps inverters cascaded with integrators with a singularity from stray positive feedback.  Both the feedback SVF and the feedforward MMF filters will tend to oscillate.

My recommendation is suppress the oscillation by reducing the BW of the inverters with 100 pF FB.

The best cost+effectiveness solution I can suggest is the TI digital tuned SVF board from the [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrbe7/tidrbe7.pdf?ts=1627617177605&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTIPD160) . They give all the design files.

https://www.ti.com/tool/TIPD160#technicaldocuments

Comment: The oscillations occur at frequencies I'm trying to filter (I'm working with audio frequencies)